# Verify Apple iOS iTunes receipt; 0-based or 1-based hour

Tags: java, ios, itunes, jackson, jodatime

I am writing a Java servlet that will verify whether Apple receipt-date from an iOS in-app purchase is valid or not, and to get a receipt object to return to the iOS client. The specification of this verification are in [this page from the official iOS documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html).

In the verified and converted **receipt** object (a JSON returned to the servlet by Apple via HTTP Post), an example a date string is this: `2012-01-13 10:14:24 America/Los_Angeles`. I want to write a [Jackson JSON deserializer](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonDeserializer.html) that will convert the String into a [Joda DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object.

**Problem**: I am not sure whether the *hour* field of the timestamp is 0-based or 1-based. If it was 0-based, then I would create a [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) using `HH` to specify the hour field. Conversely, if it was 1-based, then I would use `kk`. Please see the [Javadoc for DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for more info about how to write the timestamp configuration String.

Does anyone know whether the timestamp from Apple is 0-based or 1-based? As I do not yet have an active iTunes app (my test timestamp was from an example receipt), I am unable to write a test for this. Thank you!

Comment: I'm almost certain that it's 0-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Verifying Store Receipts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html) you can get that `purchase_date` is a `transactionDate`, and `transactionDate` [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369). From [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369) you can see that the used hour format is `HH:mm`.